# Flyspell and Ispell find different incorrect words

Tags: flyspell, ispell

There are words that are considered to be wrong by Flyspell that are instead considered correct by Ispell. I thought that Flyspell was merely an *async* version of Ispell, I must be wrong...

To add to the confusion, there cases in which `ispell-buffer` finds nothing, but `ispell-word` instead considers some words in the buffer to be wrong, coherently to what Flyspell has to say.

Here's an example:

```
$ echo http://example.com >/tmp/test
$ emacs -Q /tmp/test
```

Then execute `M-x flyspell-buffer`. The word `http` is now marked as wrong, in fact, `ispell-word` shows the usual interactive menu. Yet, `M-x ispell-buffer` completes without finding any wrong words.

Can you help me understanding what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Flyspell tries to respect Ispell as much as possible (e.g., `ispell-program-name` and `ispell-dictionary`), but does not use the functionalities exposed by Ispell to do the spell checking.

`ispell-buffer` uses `ispell-begin-skip-region-regexp` to skip over some parts of the buffer; this is what causes it to skip over `http`.

If you create a buffer called `*Ispell Debug*` and then enable debugging by evaluating `(defvar ispell-debug-buffer "*Ispell Debug*")`, you will see `ispell-buffer` print something along the lines of

```
ispell-region: Search for first region to skip after (ispell-begin-skip-region-regexp)
ispell-region: First skip: http://example.com at (pos,line,column): (1,1,0).
```

in `*Ispell Debug*`.  `ispell-word` does not do any of this skipping.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Side question: how can I achieve coherence between the two? Or should I just use Flyspell and ditch the rest? I really want something that *just works* as expected... I know it's a broad term and that we're talking about Emacs here :) but I'm open to suggestions, even third-party packages will do. In all these years I've never managed to use spellchecking in Emacs without feeling pain.